# Is there a way to reduce the opening tab of safari

Tags: safari

When opening a new tab or window in Safari, sometimes the address field is selected, and sometimes it isn't. If it's not, there's no way to tab to it. Is there a way to make the bar always selected by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no setting to do this but if you press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> the cursor will move to the address bar.

Comment: or cmf shift F to go to the search bar

Comment: In Safari 5 the shortcut for the search bar is actually Command+Option+F

Comment: same problem on yosemite OS X 10.10 also